# Unrecognized option 'b:v' when trying to convert a video

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I get "Unrecognized option `b:v`" when I tried to convert a video. I'm using FFmpeg version SVN-r26402.

Here is my error log:

```
Raw Conversion Log
Started on 2014-06-29 00:02:02 - 2014 Jun 29 

Checking File .... 
File : /home//public_html/files/conversion_queue/1403982097308ac.mov 
File Exists : Yes 

Preparing file...
format : mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 
duration : 8.2 
size : 11501692 
bitrate : 10958 
video_width : 1920 
video_height : 1080 
video_wh_ratio : 1.77777777778 
video_codec : h264 
video_rate : 30.1219512195 
video_bitrate : 10695 
video_color : N/A 
audio_codec : aac 
audio_bitrate : 255 
audio_rate : 44100 
audio_channels : stereo 
path : /home//public_html/files/conversion_queue/1403982097308ac.mov 

Converting Video 
Conversion Command : /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home//public_html/files/conversion_queue/1403982097308ac.mov -f mp4 -vcodec flv -r 25 -b:v 300000 -s 854x480 -aspect 1.77777777778 -padcolor 000000 -padtop 0 -padbottom 0 -padleft 0 -padright 0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128000 -ar 22050 /home/sillysto/public_html/files/videos/1403982097308ac-sd.mp4 2> /home/sillysto/public_html/files/temp/1403982122311e9.tmp
```

Conversion Details

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 25 2014 09:39:25 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
configuration: 
libavutil 50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
libavcore 0.16. 1 / 0.16. 1
libavcodec 52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
libavformat 52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
libavdevice 52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
libavfilter 1.74. 0 / 1.74. 0
libswscale 0.12. 0 / 0.12. 0

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1200.00 (1200/1) -> 30.00 (30/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home//public_html/files/conversion_queue/1403982097308ac.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand : qt 
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: qt 
creation_time : 2014-06-15 15:36:26
Duration: 00:00:08.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11099 kb/s
Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1080, 10908 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
Metadata:
creation_time : 2014-06-15 15:36:26
Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 258 kb/s
Metadata:
creation_time : 2014-06-15 15:36:26
Unrecognized option 'b:v'
Failed to stat file /home//public_html/files/videos/1403982097308ac-sd.mp4!
Failed to stat file /home//public_html/files/videos/1403982097308ac-sd.mp4!


Unknown file details - Unable to get output video details using FFMPEG 


Time Took : 0.0831 seconds 

conversion_status : failed
```

Comment: Where did you got your ffmpeg? What is your distro? Mine is version `2.1.4-1` and works pretty fine.

Comment: from autoffmpeg installer what is distro? i doubt my b:v command is wrong

Comment: Your command is indeed correct, but you shouldn't install software directly from the internet, always look first on your repositories and install apps or packages using a package manager like `yum` or `apt-get`. Delete that ffmpeg and try executing `yum install ffmpeg` or `apt-get install ffmpeg` on a console.

Comment: @arielnmz For ffmpeg that's not the best advice as the packaged versions are often quite outdated too.

Comment: @slhck Well, I prefer having an stable build rather than a cutting-edge unstable one, but the main focus of my comment was that he shouldn't download apps directly from the internet, that's insecure. And by the way, my ffmpeg version (from the repos) is the 2.1.4, so I don't think it's quite *outdated*.

Comment: @arielnmz In FFmpeg, cutting edge builds are more stable than anything older. In fact, it's encouraged to always run on the very latest revision, because there are so many improvements and fixed bugs. From my experience most people still run outdated distros which package ffmpeg 0.6 or something equally bad.

Comment: I've seen similar cases, but I'm glad that's not the case on fedora. But again, the core of my comment is that the op shouldn't be installing apps from any site on the internet, the repos were a suggestion but I'd encourage downloading them only from trusted sources as well. By the way by cutting edge I also mean including nightly, beta and testing releases of software too, it'd make no sense saying that cutting edge *stable* packages are less stable than non cutting edge *stable* packages.

Comment: you guys are confusing me Will you be more specific on my problem

Comment: @arielnmz You're right. The site the OP installed from looks quite weird. Note that in ffmpeg there are no nightly, beta and testing branches. There's just a ("stable") master branch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ffmpeg version is outdated. You have two options:

- Download a recent static build from [their download  page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- Compile it yourself according to [the Wiki instructions](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)

The new versions recognize `b:v` as an option.

---

Also, you should update your command. This is the old one:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec flv -r 25 -b:v 300000 \
-s 854x480 -aspect 1.77777777778 \
-padcolor 000000 -padtop 0 -padbottom 0 -padleft 0 -padright 0 \
-acodec libmp3lame -ab 128000 -ar 22050 output.mp4
```

First, you do not need the `-f mp4`. I'm also not sure if you really want FLV as video codec. This is quite inefficient. You probably want MPEG-4 Part II or MPEG-4 AVC video. The latter delivers better quality and is compatible with HTML5 and most devices nowadays. MP3 audio can also be exchanged to AAC audio.

We choose `-c:v libx264` for the x264 encoder, and we use a [constant rate factor](http://slhck.info/articles/crf) to set the quality. 23 is default, and sane values are between 18 and 28. Less is better quality. You can also set a constant bitrate instead using `-b:v 500k`, for example. The [x264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) gives you more details.

Furthermore, the `-pad*` options were removed and you have to use [the `pad` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad). The `-aspect` option seems unnecessary to me.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -r 25 -crf 23 \
-s 854x480 \
-vf "pad=width=1920:height=1080:x=0:y=0:color=black" \
-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ar 22050 output.mp4
```

If you need compatibility with devices that don't have a lot of processing power, add `-profile:v baseline` as an option.

Comment: i get sh: /home/root/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory

Comment: There is no `/home/root/bin`, only `/root/bin`. You can check the full current path with `pwd` from a terminal. If you call `which -a ffmpeg`, you can see which versions of ffmpeg are available for you in your executable PATH. Regarding your query: I am available for personal consulting if you need help with video encoding or web video. You can find contact details [on my website](http://slhck.info/).

Comment: @sirus Also, if you call it from PHP, you need to make sure that `/home/root/bin/ffmpeg` is readable and executable for the Apache user. I'd rather do a `cp /home/root/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg_new` and `chmod og+rx /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg_new`, and then call `exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg_new ...')` from PHP.

Comment: did i have to use crons for video conversion

Comment: @sirus Not sure what you mean exactly. You don't have to use `cron` (I suppose?) for converting videos. If you're developing a web app where these conversion jobs happen in the background, PHP offers quite a lot of libraries that allow you to do that, e.g. Gearman